# Java:Why http session is not destroyed when tab or browser is closed?

Tags: java, session

I have the following implementation of HttpSessionlistener

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener {


public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
   ...

}


public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {

    ...
}

public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {

}

//HttpSesion creation & destruction
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    //log created time


}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    long destroyedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //log destroyed time

}
```

}

Basically i log the session creation and destruction time.
But if the session is long (default to 30 minutes), and user closes browser meanwhile, the

```
sessionDestroyed
```

is not called ?

Why is that ? 
Is there a workaround to log exactly the when the session was destroyed (when user closes the browser)? Should'nt be this be the browser's problem, to kill the session when it is closed ?

Is there any interface that i have to implement for this to work ?

Thank you !

Comment: I am 100% sure that this is possible at least in 2016. Many sites do that, they close the session once you close the Tab in Google Chrome!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How would the server know when the browser is closed or the tab closed? At that point the browser doesn't send anything to the server.

This is a fundamental part of HTTP - it's a request/response protocol, not a "permanently open conversation" where you can tell if one party leaves the conversation. Think of it as a series of telegrams rather than a phone call - and you can't tell when you've received the last telegram you're going to get.

You'll need to design your way round this - to avoid *needing* to know when the browser has been closed. There are some ugly hacks to work around it - making AJAX poll the server with a heartbeat message, for example - but changing the design is a better solution.

Comment: you explained is properly I really appreciate that but can u suggest a way through which we can achieve it like we can destroy session while closing browser tab

Comment: @dom: No, I've explained why that's impossible to do reliably, other than with ugly hacks such as a heartbeat polling the server to keep the session alive.

Answer (score 6):

*NOTE:* As [jwenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706224/javawhy-http-session-is-not-destroyed-when-tab-or-browser-is-closed/1121034#comment-8129744) commented below, this it's not 100% safe at all. If the the onunload event does not get triggered by a closing event of the browser tab or window, then this would fail.

I had the same problem, and solve it using an intrusive JavaScript event:

```
window.onunload
```

Let me briefly explain, lets say you have a JavaScript function that post, using jQuery, the current Session ID to that Servlet to invalidate it, like this:

```
function safeexit(){
   $.post("/SessionKillServlet", { SID = <%=session.getId()%> }, function(data){});
}
```

To call that function, you just need to bind it like these:

```
window.onunload =  safeexit;  //without the ()
```

Now, safeexit method will be called when the TAB or BROWSER WINDOW gets closed (or in a redirection).

Comment: better late than never: don't do this! It's not safe, the onunload event does not get triggered for all ways in which a window can be closed.

Comment: Indeed, but for the scenario I had to solve, sadly, I had to implement it :S

Comment: I know. Had to do the same one time, and despite the warnings given that it wouldn't work we still got complaints from the very people we'd warned that it didn't work...

Comment: @jwenting: I edited my answer to add a reference to your comment. Better late than never ;)

Comment: This is a bad idea, because `onunload` will be invoked on various events, not only when browser becomes closed.

Comment: Could  you please provide a link or a full list of events that will trigger `onunload`?

Answer (score 2):

Session objects live in the server and are controlled by the server. Only the server can create or destroy sessions. So if the client is closed the session lives until it expires. The client can only suggest to the server that it can destroy some session. This request must be explicit somehow. Hence, when you close a browser window, there's no implicit request to the server informing that it must destroy a given session.

Answer (score 1):

With out a lot of work the browser does not inform the server that the window is closed, therefore Java can not know when to destroy the session. Hence the time out is in place and is the first the server knows that this session can be distroyed.

You could try and play an ajax call on the javascript event document.onunload 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload but you will need to be sure that the user is not still within your site when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the session to be destroyed when a browser window/tab is closed you might attach a JavaScript handler to the onunload event that makes some sort of AJAX call to a resource that call kill the session.

Note that the onunload event does not always fire so it's not totally trustworthy. One trusty way might be to use a "heartbeat" system.

Answer (score 1):

there is some hacks for knows
following code for destroy session when user closes browser

> client side:

```
<script src="jquery path"></script>
<script>
  window.onunload = function(){ $.get("${request.contextPath}/logout"); }
</script>
```

> server side: create request mapping for "/logout"

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse) {
  request.getSession().invalidate();
  System.out.println('destroy from logout on unload browser');
}
```

> Following code is optional
>
> use session listener when want to know when session destroyed

```
//    in class

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class SesListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
   System.out.println("Session created...");
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    System.out.println("Session destroyed...");
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------

// in web.xml
<listener>
   <listener-class>SesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eric mentioned the unload event on the browser can call a javascript function, which in turn can access an url through a servlet that logs you out. You need not wait for the actual response from the servlet.

The web browser interacts with the server through the http protocol and that is stateless.

Answer (score -1):

you can just verify if your session user , aren't null like :

```
if (session.getAttribute("user") != null )
   sessionsetAttribute("user","null");
```